# What is the current consensus on COVID-19's infection fatality rate?

Tags: covid-19, statistics

I've been looking for a solid, commonly accepted range of plausible COVID-19 infection fatality rate numbers. I'd expect this to be somewhat easily found on the CDC's or WHO's website, but I've come up blank. The closest I've come is [this CDC page](https://www.cdc.gov/coronavirus/2019-ncov/covid-data/investigations-discovery/hospitalization-death-by-age.html), which frustratingly shows relative rates but zero absolute numbers.

I know there are difficulties in estimating the IFR for a disease that can present asymptomatically, or mildly such that one might not bother going to the hospital or getting tested - but I'd be happy with an order-of-magnitude estimate.

By common sense observation, I'm pretty sure it's not 10%, and I'm pretty sure it's not 0.000001%, but it's frustratingly difficult to find a commonly agreed-upon range. Surely those making policy decisions about this disease have estimates they work off of, and surely those would be made publicly available - I just can't find it.

This has been [previously asked](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/23565/what-data-and-research-is-available-on-the-mortality-risk-infection-fatality-ra) - more than a year ago, when the IFR estimates seemed to be in the 0.1-1% range. I'm hoping to find more recent data & research, and I'm interested in which way this has been trending.

Comment: Covid is changing from variant to variant, the demographics of the infected populations are changing , exposure modes are likely changing, and who knows if the rate of asymptomatic vs symptomatic illness is changing. It's not surprising there don't seem to be good numbers.